# How does the html table tag does not working inside the ng-template(Angularjs)?

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-template

I have tried the following using ui.bootstrap.modal). 
Here is the code that I am using for the bootstrap.modal:
In the HTML file:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Program Account Checklist!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                        <table>
                            <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Is your organization:</th>
                                <th>CRA Program Account</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> checkbot </td>
                                    <td> info </td>
                                    <td> account </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="">Clear</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </script>
```

In my controller.js:

```
 $scope.open = function() {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.checklist;
            }
          },
        size: 'lg'
    })
```

Now the problem is that when I tried to pop up a window with a table in it, the data are showing on the right position, but there isn't any ui for the table. Everything seems like in the plain text. I guess it has something to do with the  type="text/ng-template". But I couldn't figure out a way to work around it. How can I resolve this problem?
  [image: Here is my Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, You are missing bootstrap styling on the table?, In that case add some class names like so:

```
<table class="table table-borderless">

</table>
```